# How to rbind in for loop?

Tags: r, rbind

As you can see , I have a problem.
I really want to do `rbind` fuction in for loop.
But the error is appeared below.

My data set is named like `tt_1`, `tt_2` ...
The code is below.
How can I do `rbind` those data sets?

```
for ( jj in 1 : 84) {
         tt_count <- rbind.data.frame(tt_count, tt_jj)
         count.maxTemp <- tt_count
}
```

> Error in rbind.data.frame(tt_count, tt_jj) : object 'tt_jj' not     found

Comment: You did''nt created any `tt_jj` in your loop so `rbind` has nothing to bind with `tt_count`

Comment: I have to create the tt date set in the same loop?

Comment: And I made a tt_count as ‘data.frame(matrix(nrow=1,ncol=2))’.

Comment: So if you okay, could you give me some sample code?

Comment: You cannot use jj as an index in the name of the variable the way you are trying to do.

Comment: But I have tt_1, tt_2. like those. At the prior for loop, I created tt_1 ~tt_84.

Comment: Try to create a list of your "tt" dataframes and check the suggestion below

Comment: If you created the tt_i in a previous loop, and your goal is to rbind them all together, it would probably be easiest to rbind them in that loop, as you create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a guess you could solve this by using a list of dataframes named `myList` :

```
tt_count <- NULL # the dataframe to fill  
for (i in length(myList)) {
tt_count <- rbind(tt_count, myList[[i]]) 
}
```